# vba Outlook appointment unique ID

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for unique item ID for appointments. Thing is that `EntryID` is the same for all recurrences. Is there any option to get unique ID for every recurrences as well?

thx in advance

edit

I'm importing details to excel then in excel adding some more data and format them later. Thing is that I have to give to User option to choose dates (from-to) and for simplicity I take easiest way and I prevent user to import data which date of appointment < last appointment date in excel. But now I need to add that functionality, and because everything in appointment can change, I thought the easiest way to check if both appointments are the same(outlook and excel) will be to check IDs, but if recurrences IDs are the same then I need to work in `RecurrencePattern` and based on `EntryID` (which I will store in Excel for ref) find if that entry in excel are correct for that pattern, because user can always change appointments in outlook and then export again. And because of that possibility to change recurrence appointments I thought that unique IDs will give me less to code.
  If my point is right then I need to handle recurrence exceptions too.

Comment: i would take "entryID & startdate" as unique ID - woudln't that work?

Comment: I updated question -> When someone change recurrence appointment and import it again then I will not find that appointment in excel

Answer (score 0):

Recurrences do not physically exist (think of an appointment with no end date). Outlook will create an id (based on the master appointment id) when you create an exception.

What exactly are you trying to do and why?